# Visual Leak Detector does not work

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, memory-leaks, memory-leak-detector, visual-leak-detector

I have just started using [Visual Leak Detector for Visual C++ 2008/2010](http://vld.codeplex.com/)

When i run it on small app (just few line with undeleted allocations) it works just fine.

Now I want to run it into my bigger app (wxWidgets app, 2 threads), but when I include

```
#include <vld.h>
```

my app does not completely start up. It starts cycling when Gui is created. Somethimes app load completely, but again, stuck when I for example press some button...

When I hit pause button, to see which code is being processed I see just

[image: stack: ntdll, kernel...]

Is anybody run into similar problem?

Is there any way to make it work?

Comment: Have you tried testing it on a simpler 2-thread program? Maybe it has multi-threading issues. Also, if your program is resource-hungry, keep in mind that leak detectors tend to be a major performance hit. You might just be witnessing major slowness (or maybe not).

Comment: @Brandon Bohrer: I have not tried simpler 2threaded program, but I will... It is not just slow start, because some other "lucky" time it start up in few secs.

Comment: The call stack contains nvoglv32.dll. Are you sure you're looking at the correct thread? NVidia drivers start up some more threads that do the actual rendering in an OpenGL application.

Comment: You can to use deleaker or similary tool for detect memory leak...fast and easy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Visual Leak Detector makes the App run VERY slowly, be patient.

Are you running a single binary file?

I'v had issues when my program was split into the main executable and libraries loaded on the run.

The solution was to do the #include everywhere, especially the executable.

Note that you can use VLDDisable and VLDEnable if you want to target specific parts of the code, note that these work per thread. Disabling in one thread doesn't modify what goes on in others.

Answer (score 0):

This is not exactly an answer to this specific question, but it fixed my problem and I wanted to document it somewhere somebody else may be able to find it helpful to them.

I was linking a program with vld and got

```
fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) class     VisualLeakDetector vld" (__imp_?vld@@3VVisualLeakDetector@@A)
```

I did a dumpbin of vld.lib and noticed that it has an external called

```
      F26 __imp_?g_vld@@3VVisualLeakDetector@@A
```

notice the "g_"

So changed my vld.h from

```
#pragma comment(linker, "/include:__imp_?vld@@3VVisualLeakDetector@@A")
to
#pragma comment(linker, "/include:__imp_?g_vld@@3VVisualLeakDetector@@A")
```

and then it linked and worked just fine.

again, hopefully google will be able to find this answer for people having vld linking problems.